# Error: There is an undefined binding (serviceConsultas) in the WSDL document Consultas) in the WSDL document https

Tags: .net, web-services, wsdl

I have a wsdl file and i am generating WSDL2Java from this wsdl file. 
I am getting this IOException

```
IWAB0399E Error al generar Java a partir de WSDL:  java.io.IOException: Emitter failure.  There is an undefined binding (serviceConsultas) in the WSDL document https://webuatlab.vignet.com.ar/services/serviceConsultas.svc?wsdl.
Hint: make sure <port binding=".."> is fully qualified. 
org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.checkForUndefined(SymbolTable.java:575)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:715)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:734)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:734)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.add(SymbolTable.java:543)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:518)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:495)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:361)
```

Regards,
Silvio

Comment: It looks like a parsing error caused by serviceConsultas being used somewhere in the WSDL file but the file not describing what it is. It would help to include the WSDL file.

Comment: Hi Matt this is WSDL https://drive.google.com/file/d/1osS58oMP_yLW4vzmjAkWyt88GmLoGfbv/view?usp=sharing       any idea? thanks, Silvio

Comment: The problem is with `<wsdl:port name="serviceConsultas" binding="i0:serviceConsultas">`. This is the binding it can't find. `i0` is the abbreviation for the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/02/mex/bindings` namespace and `serviceConsultas` is the name in that namespace. The namespace is being imported from https://webuatlab.vignet.com.ar/services/serviceConsultas.svc?wsdl=wsdl0 . This is the file that should contain a binding named `serviceConsultas`. It's not available online so I hope it's available on your intranet.